# Apache Superset seems to pick up my local configuration but url_param has no effect

Tags: python, apache-superset

I'm running Apache Superset 1.4.0 on a Debian server, inside a Python virtual environment.

According to the official documentation at https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/sql-templating, if I set `ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING` to `True` in `superset_config.py`, I should be able to pass URL query parameters to Apache Superset, and use them in my SQL queries, so that I can have dynamic SQL queries.

But I still can't have that. I create the configuration file with the required contents:

```
$ cat /home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/superset_config.py
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True,
}
```

And restarted the Apache Superset service. Checking the logs, it seems like it picked the configuration file I've created as described above:

```
$ journalctl | grep superset | grep configuration
Jan 27 14:52:18 dashboard-server python[12204]: Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/superset_config.py]
Jan 27 15:15:45 dashboard-server python[12215]: Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/superset_config.py]
Jan 27 15:15:57 dashboard-server python[12406]: Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/superset_config.py]
```

Then I first checked a super simple query to see Superset is working fine:

```
SELECT 'USA' as query_parameter
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0;
```

[image]

Now I change the query as the following, save it, and COPY LINK of this **dynamic** query:

```
SELECT '{{ url_param('country') }}' as query_parameter
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0;
```

Then I add `&country=USA` at the end of it, but unfortunately it doesn't run the dynamical query I want, in the screenshot below the URL is changed by Apache Superset, but what I entered was `http: ... sqllab/?savedQueryId=4&country=USA`:

[image]

I don't get any results. It only says "Run a query to display results here". But I'd expect the same result, I mean I'd expect Apache Superset to retrieve the value USA from the URL parameter named `country` and use this in the SQL query.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**: The templating functionality seems to work for `{{ current_username() }}` macro, but still not for `{{ url_param('country') }}` macro:

[image]

Comment: I've just edited my post to add the fact that the templating functionality seems to work for `{{ current_username() }}` macro, but still not for `{{ url_param('country') }}` macro.

Comment: I watched this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5v0keE_RlSA and now I can use a ``{{ url_param(' ... ` macro in a dashboard, but sill not in SQL Lab. Any idea why? Is it impossible to do that in SQL Lab?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think URL parameters work on SQL lab. What you will have to do is run the original query

```
SELECT 'USA' as query_parameter
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0;
```

Save and explore the query. Once you go to the charts section you can edit the dataset to include the Jinja templating with URL parameters.

```
SELECT '{{ url_param('country') }}' as query_parameter
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0;
```

Save it and then you can test if it works by editing the URL while still on the explorer tab.